# Where are the theme options for the spacebar search menu?

Tags: customization, theme

Where are the color options for the spacebar search menu background?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be *Inner Selected* and the color options can be found under *Menu Back*.

**NB:** Changing some of these values will affect similar popup dialogs.

[image]